# net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing null: null

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I have java code to transform xml using xslt but when I am running it getting below exception-

```
cationContext@1698c449: startup date [Tue Jun 30 15:10:33 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-06-30 15:10:36.441  INFO 23000 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Error
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing null: null
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing null: null
        at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:152)
        at com.manh.xml2json.XsltTester.xmlToJsonUsingXslSaxon(XsltTester.java:116)
        at com.manh.xml2json.XsltTester.run(XsltTester.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:723)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:713)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.manh.xml2json.XsltTester.main(XsltTester.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing null: null
```

**Here is my java code-**

```
    private void xmlToJsonUsingXslSaxon(String xmlFileName, String xslFileName, String outFileName){
        Transformer transformer;
        Templates templates;
        try {
            templates = new net.sf.saxon.BasicTransformerFactory().newTemplates(
                    new StreamSource(XsltTester.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream(xslFileName)));
            transformer = templates.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFileName)), new StreamResult(new File(outFileName)));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
}
```

****Note -**  I am running this java program by executing jar with below command-**

```
 java -jar ./libs/xslt-tester-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --mode=xsl --infile=input.xml --outfile=output.json --xsl=./xslt/myxslt.xsl
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` returns null if the resource cannot be found, and that's what the stacktrace suggests is happening here.

Comment: I resolved this one by changing TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();.

Comment: I find it very hard to understand why that should fix the problem. I suspect you changed something else as well.

Answer (score 0):

After changing as below worked for me.

```
private void transformXmlUsingXsl(String xmlFileName, String xslFileName, String outFileName){

        //TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();

        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslFileName)));
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFileName)), new StreamResult(new File(outFileName)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
```